# Is it possible to access AIDL service from another device?

Tags: android, sockets, aidl

I am developing an app in which I want to access AIDL service running
on different device.

Any way to achieve this? I didn't find any solution.

I am able to connect to a service, from client app running on same device..
Want to do this over remote machines.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: no, you can not do that

Comment: any other way to access service...indirectly?

Comment: Read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html), it is not a Remoting system! Use sockets and custom server on device where Aidl is used and let clients connect and server delegates tasks, you are using the wrong approach as AIDL is within device boundaries as far as IPC mechanism is concerned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is not possible to use AIDL for remote connection.